# Export MySQL Server database to file

Tags: java, mysql, export

I have recently put all my java EE projects into my google drive so i can access them on my laptop and desktop computer. Some of my projects have a database component which I have the database stored in a MySQL server. Is there a way that I can export this database and just access it from like a database file which I can store in my project file so I can use it on both my laptop and desktop computer?

This is really what I would like:
-Be able to work on my java EE projects that have a database on both my computers 
-Store my MySQL Server databases in a file which can go in my project folder then use java to access that database instead of going through the server

Any alternate ways of doing this would help me out this is just one way I can think of doing.

Note: I am using my laptop on the go so my desktop computer wont always be accessible from my laptop neither will I have an active internet connection always.
Thanks

Comment: exporting mydql server database to file through java program or manually in mysql console

Comment: Google drive? That isn't a code version control system. Consider Github/Bitbucket/etc.

Answer (score 0):

Install MySQL on your laptop, then transfer database using backup/restore, e.g. using mysqldump. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/backup-and-recovery.html